# Is a palindrome a thing?

Tags: grammar

A palindrome is a word or phrase that is the same backwards and forwards, such as "Bob", "aibohphobia" or "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama."

In English, as well as many other languages, this is a coherent, named concept and literary technique.

Does a meaningfully similar concept exist in Japanese, and is it used?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaibun

Comment: 回分 shows up in JDIC (http://jisho.org/search/palindrome) but not on goo via デジタル大辞泉 (http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E5%9B%9E%E5%88%86/m0u/) which is a bit worrying.  This page seems to allude to it's usage as meaning palindrome: http://kaibun.jp/

Comment: Somebody called 有馬 once told me that his name is easy for foreigners to remember, because it is the reverse of "Maria". Needless to say, foreigners that would *not* be confused by this statement (i.e., those having internalized the syllabic nature of Japanese), probably wouldn't have a problem remembering 有馬 in the first place...

Comment: @naruto Oops, right you are.  Definition 2: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/36915/meaning/m0u/%E5%9B%9E%E6%96%87/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

「ないな」わいは[い]{言}わないな。
[よる]{夜}は[しんさく]{新作}たくさんしはるよ。
[わたし]{私}[かいぶん]{回文}[ぜんぶ]{全部}[い]{活}かしたわ。

(Ah don' say "there ain't".
They create many new works at night.
I made good use of all (my) palindromes!")

---

おそまつさまでした。

---

*UPDATE:*

> 回文であるはいくはどうですか？

[ひと]{人}は[と]{問}ひ　「[とくい]{得意}？[はいく]{俳句}」と　[ひと]{人}は[と]{問}ひ

(They ask me / "Good at haiku?"—so / they ask me)

Comment: 回文であるはいくはどうですか？

Comment: @WillihamTotland 追加しました^^

Comment: 素敵な一句やな。（このサイトも15字は必要やな）

Answer (score 16):

We have a word, 回文{かいぶん}, for instance:

- 竹藪焼{たけやぶや}けた - "The bamboo bush was burnt"
- 英語{えいご}言{い}え - "Speak (in) English"
- イタリアで暮{く}らし楽{らく}でありたい - "I want to live comfortably in Italy"

as a counterpart to the English "palindrome".

There are hundreds and hundreds of 回文, but I cannot recall them off the top of my head. I think you can collect them by googling 回文.

Answer (score 4):

There was a great little song on ピタゴラスイッチ about these!

> こたつたこ ⇒ Kotatsu Octopus
>
> ミセスセミ ⇒ Mrs. Cicada
>
> くりりりく ⇒ Chestnut Take-off
>
> えびねびえ ⇒ Shrimp's stomach gets cold and he gets diarrhea in the middle of the night...

Here's a link to the video like I saw it on TV...
http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm13345793

Answer (score 0):

> Is a palindrome a thing ?

It's a bigger thing in Japan, in the sense that more people are making them, and great ones are being produced / invented every day. (like broccoli forest 's above)

Older "kaibun" had no Dakuten :

> 昔のひらがなの文には濁点がほとんど（全部？）ついてません... 
>   detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp ›
>
> 下のような回文が濁点なしで成り立ちます。 「なかきよの とおのねふりの みなめさめ なみのりふねの おとのよきかな」 漢字を入れて書くと、 「長き夜のとおの眠りのみな目覚め波乗り舟の音の良きかな」 濁点付ければ、 「ながきよのとのねぶり（ ...

---

ヽ(ｏﾟ∀ﾟｏ)ﾉ 　「いざ！　濁点し、日本語 Ｓ Ｅ　投稿 ... と」 
　　　→　　　「いいス」　（エゴ、ン？）　「ボツ に し<sub>ン</sub>て下さい」　(´；Д；｀)

いさ、　だくてんし　にっぽんご　えすいい　とうこう ...　と 
　　　　　　→　いいす　（えご、　ん）　ぼつ　に　しんて　ください

---

Here's a sampling from 2014.

> http://woman.mynavi.jp/article/140209-96/
>
> 「タイム！　リスが擦りむいた！」
>
> 「弱虫のタモリが信濃での梨狩りも楽しむわよ」
>
> 「イタリアでもホモでありたい」
>
> 「うそ、死の谷意外に楽しそう」
>
> 「あああああ竹やぶ焼けたあああああ」　　　 <--- 　　　  w w w

Song  [ 世迷い言 ―よまいごと―　]　　　by 　　　歌：中島みゆき 　　　作詞：阿久悠

> ♪ 　　真夜中　世の中　世迷い言 
>   　 ♪ 　　 上から読んでも下から読んでも
>
> ♪ 　　「世の中バカなのよ」

「世の中ね顔かお金かなのよ」

---

Related item  　　　-----  　　　( Has this been mentioned here already? )

> [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/たいこめ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%82%81)
>
> たいこめとは言葉遊びの一つ。ある文を後ろから逆に読み返ると、全く違う意味の通る文のこと。 「たいつりぶねにこめおしだるま（鯛釣り船に米押しダルマ）」の略で「たいこめ」。同文をひっくり返すと別の文章（下ネタ）が現れることから、略して「たいこめ」と ...
>
> . . . . . .  . . . 
>    同様の言葉遊びに「雲雲崖に こんち旅無し（くもくもがけにこんちたびなし）」 「飛べ飛べツチノコ（とべとべつちのこ）」といったものがあり、地方、時代によって様々なものが存在したことが窺える。